# Unable to open zipalign faiiled error in Flutter Signed APK build

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, flutter, zipalign

Trying to generate a signed APK build for my flutter app.

But getting a zipalign error in it
[image]

Using Eclipse as Java Compiler . How to fix that issue?
Runned flutter clean also multiple times

Comment: Please add additional information like IDE details, the way used to generate APK.

Comment: Using Android Studio to generate apk